# What chips can be used to design an Anti-Counterfeit /Authentication circuit?

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, communication

I am an intern within the R&D branch of a company that designs tools that must operate with low noise at extremely high external temperatures (upwards of 175C). My boss asked that I look into finding a chip that would help prevent counterfeit tools from being connected to our power supply.

I'm looking for a chip that will check for a certain serial number or a "password" of sorts before allowing operation of the tool. In other words, the chip would expect to be given a correct response from the tool being attached to the power supply before allowing the tool to be operated.

I have found chips like the ATSHA204A (https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATsha204a), but I can't figure out how it should actually be connected to operate the way described above - I'm not even sure if this type of chip would be useful for what I have been tasked with.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a microcontroller?

Comment: An off-the-shelf solution won't help you as any "counterfeit" instrument manufacturer can buy and use it.

Comment: The chip ATsha204a you linked to is only rated to 85C.  I don't see it operating at 175C.

Comment: @Toor A tamper-resistant microcontroller protected from reading. And the handshake protocol with the instrument has to be encrypted or otherwise cryptographically protected.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent your power supply being used for other devices? This reminds me of the FTDI fiasco a little while back.

Comment: There are very few products (PCB's and the components) that can operated at 175degC.  Are you talking about tool temperatures of 175degC ...or Ambient or operating temperatures at that level.

Comment: The ATSHA204A is a great device, and it would certainly raise tha bar for authentication of the tools. How do you want it to operate??? Do you want to send negotiation/authentication traffic over the power supply cable, or run separate communications lines between the tool and power supply. It's impossible to help you without any clue of what your company might want.

Comment: As a random customer I hate when companise do this. Maybe your industry has a good reason for doing it but most likely not. If it was about using counterfeit *power supplies* with *your tool* there would at least be an inkling of a reason, but I don't see why your power supply shouldn't be able to supply power to anything that wants it.

Comment: Apple, it that you? or is it John Deere? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever $0.25 micro-controller you want.  Put one controller in your power supply and another one in each device you want to attach.

The controller in both devices (supply and attached peripheral) contain a 128-bit secret key K.

The supply sends out a 128-bit random challenge word W that never repeats.  The seed for the challenge word W should be stored using non-volatile memory in such a way that the seed does not reset if you loose power (to avoid play-back attacks).

The device sends back the SHA-512 hash H1 of K xor W.

The controller in the supply also computes the same hash H2.  If H1 and H2 match then the attached device knows the secret key and is therefore authenticated.  If H1 does not match H2 then the attached device is either broken or counterfeit.

This scheme avoids ever sending the secret key K between the devices.  Therefore no-one can record it.

Any code-protection in the controller in both devices should be turned on so no-one can read out your secret key by opening the boxes.

Comment: Once and adversary owns one "genuine" device they can use it as an oracle to authenticate an arbitrary number of fake ones. But I guess this threat model is too advanced here. And of course the key once compromised, there is no way to revoke it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Couldn't you still revoke it by allowing some code to order the chip to self-write some OTP fuses?

Comment: @Toor Sure you can if you implement such a mechanism. Also you need a way to trigger it.